# A very simple TCP server/client in C# occasionally drops packets. What can I do to prevent this?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I've got an intra-PC communication server / client set up to send and receive data from one program to another - in this case, a custom server that is listening to text commands and Unity3D.

For the most part, it works, however every once in awhile, it will drop packets, and Unity will not get them without multiple attempts. The packets seem to be sent but lost, as I do see the "Sent message" console log. The following is the code for the server and client:

SERVER:

```
class TCPGameServer
{
    public event EventHandler Error;

    public Action<Data> ADelegate;

    TcpListener TCPListener;
    TcpClient TCPClient;
    Client ActiveClient;

    NetworkStream networkStream;

    StreamWriter returnWriter;
    StreamReader streamReader;

    Timer SystemTimer = new Timer();
    Timer PingTimer = new Timer();

    int Port = 8637;

    public TCPGameServer()
    {
        TCPListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, Port);
        SystemTimer.Elapsed += StreamTimer_Tick;
        SystemTimer.AutoReset = true;
        SystemTimer.Interval = 2000;

        PingTimer.Elapsed += PingTimer_Tick;
        PingTimer.AutoReset = true;
        PingTimer.Interval = 30000;
    }

    public void OpenListener()
    {
        TCPListener.Start();
        TCPListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTCPCallBack, null);
        Console.WriteLine("Network Open.");
    }

    public void GameLogout()
    {
        SystemTimer.AutoReset = false;
        SystemTimer.Stop();

        PingTimer.AutoReset = false;
        PingTimer.Stop();

        ActiveClient = null;

        returnWriter.Dispose();
        streamReader.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("The client has logged out successfully.");
    }

    private void AcceptTCPCallBack(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        TCPClient = null;
        ActiveClient = null;
        returnWriter = null;
        streamReader = null;

        try
        {
            TCPClient = TCPListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(asyncResult);

            TCPListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTCPCallBack, null);


            ActiveClient = new Client(TCPClient);
            networkStream = ActiveClient.NetworkStream;

            returnWriter = new StreamWriter(TCPClient.GetStream());
            streamReader = new StreamReader(TCPClient.GetStream());

            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected Successfully.");

            Data Packet = new Data();
            Packet.cmdCommand = Command.Login;
            Packet.strName = "Server";
            Packet.strMessage = "LOGGEDIN";
            SendMessage(Packet);


            SystemTimer.AutoReset = true;
            SystemTimer.Enabled = true;
            SystemTimer.Start();

            Ping();

            PingTimer.AutoReset = true;
            PingTimer.Enabled = true;
            PingTimer.Start();

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnError(TCPListener, ex);
            return;
        }


    }

    private void StreamTimer_Tick(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckStream();
    }

    private void PingTimer_Tick(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ping();
    }

    private void Ping()
    {
        if (TCPClient.Connected)
        {
            Data Packet = new Data();
            Packet.cmdCommand = Command.Ping;
            Packet.strName = "Server";
            Packet.strMessage = "PING";

            SendMessage(Packet);
        }
    }


    public void CheckStream()
    {
        try
        {
            if (TCPClient.Available > 0 || streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                string PacketString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                Data packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(PacketString);

                switch (packet.cmdCommand)
                {
                    case Command.Logout:
                        GameLogout();
                        break;
                    case Command.Message:
                        if (ADelegate != null)
                        {
                            ADelegate(packet);
                        }
                        break;
                    case Command.Ping:
                        Console.WriteLine("PONG!");
                        break;
               }
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        } catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void SendMessage(Data packet)
    {
        if (ActiveClient != null)
        {
            string packetMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);
            returnWriter.WriteLine(packetMessage);
            returnWriter.Flush();
        }
    }


    public void OnError(object sender, Exception ex)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Error;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            ErrorEventArgs e = new ErrorEventArgs(ex);
            handler(sender, e);
        }
    }

    public void RegisterActionDelegate(Action<Data> RegisterDelegate)
    {
        ADelegate += RegisterDelegate;
    }

    public void UnRegisterActionDelegate(Action<Data> UnregisterDelegate)
    {
        ADelegate -= UnregisterDelegate;
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
public class TCPNetworkClient
{

    public Action<Data> PacketDelegate;

    public TcpClient TCPClient;
    int Port = 8637;

    StreamReader streamReader;
    StreamWriter streamWriter;

    Timer StreamTimer = new Timer();

    public bool LoggedIn = false;



    public void Start()
    {
        if (LoggedIn == false)
        {
            TCPClient = null;
            StreamTimer.AutoReset = true;
            StreamTimer.Interval = 2000;
            StreamTimer.Elapsed += StreamTimer_Tick;


            try
            {
                TCPClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", Port);

                streamReader = new StreamReader(TCPClient.GetStream());
                streamWriter = new StreamWriter(TCPClient.GetStream());

                StreamTimer.Enabled = true;
                StreamTimer.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Log(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }

    private void StreamTimer_Tick(System.Object source,    System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TCPClient.Available > 0 || streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string PacketString = streamReader.ReadLine();
            Data packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(PacketString);

            PacketDelegate(packet);
        } 
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        Data Packet = new Data();
        Packet.cmdCommand = Command.Logout;
        Packet.strMessage = "LOGOUT";
        Packet.strName = "Game";
        SendMessage(Packet);

        if (streamReader != null && streamWriter != null)
        {
            streamReader.Dispose();
            streamWriter.Dispose();
            TCPClient.Close();
            TCPClient = null;
            streamReader = null;
            streamWriter = null;
        }

        StreamTimer.Stop();
    }

    public void SendMessage(Data packet)
    {
        string packetMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);

        try
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine(packetMessage);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void RegisterActionDelegate(Action<Data> RegisterDelegate)
    {
        PacketDelegate += RegisterDelegate;
    }

    public void UnRegisterActionDelegate(Action<Data> UnregisterDelegate)
    {
        PacketDelegate -= UnregisterDelegate;
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what's going on, or if there are any more additional checks that I need to add into the system. Note: It's TCP so that "when" this fully works, I can drop the client into other programs that I might write that may not fully rely or use Unity.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more logging to your client's `StreamTimer_Tick` method, i.e. one trace at method enter, before the `if`, and one which will dump the actual string received from `streamReader.ReadLine()`. What timer are you using? If `streamReader.ReadLine()` blocks, does `StreamTimer_Tick` get invoked again on a separate thread? If you also use Wireshark to capture all traffic, you will see if the packet gets actually sent or not. Also, I don't see a `"Sent message"` message in your code above anywhere.

Comment: I have voted to close the question because according to the OP his current code is not the code that is posted here. It's impossible to diagnose code that is not here. Progress on this question seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

1. `new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", Port)` is not appropriate for the client. Just use `TcpClient()`. There is no need to specify IP and port, both of which will end up being wrong.
2. `TCPClient.Available` is almost always a bug. You seem to assume that TCP is packet based. You can't test whether a full message is incoming or not. TCP only offers a boundaryless stream of bytes. Therefore, this `Available` check does not tell you if a whole line is available. Also, there could be multiple lines. The correct way to read is to have a reading loop always running and simply reading lines without checking. Any line that arrives will be processed that way. No need for timers etc.
3. The server has the same problems.

Issue (2) might have caused the appearance of lost packets somehow. You need to fix this in any case.

Comment: Although those checks in 2. are incorrect as you stated, I thought `StreamReader.ReadLine` will block until a `NL` character is received?

Comment: It does. I'm not sure how the appearance of lost packets came to be. Maybe there were two messages at once and only one was read? Report back when you have fixed and updated the code. It's pointless to discuss this clearly broken code.

Comment: Interesting, and honestly a bit rude. I did remove .Available from both sides, and I added logging. The string being sent is coming across as blank from the client-side reader every so often, seemingly a 20% chance of it. As for TcpClient, it does actually require a IP address and port. The reason for that may be it's operating on 2.0 with some 3.5 - while the server is on 4.0. The difference in versions is due to Unity.

Comment: `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1d0e0f(v=vs.80).aspx` should work on 2.0. So you're saying that `PacketString` can end up being ""? I don't see how that is possible. Add Debug.Assert(PacketString != ""). Or is it null instead of blank? Regarding rude, it's necessary to expedite resolving complex questions like this one. Often, the OP does not comply with tests or changes that are being asked. Indeed, you did not update the code in the question. It's really hard helping under such circumstances when there is an error caused by code that I don't see.